# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мыши на ссылку появился блок?

Tags: html, css

Ну, примерно так:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/wc2uje8e/2/

```css
.block-to-show {
    display: none;
}

.link-to-hover:hover ~ .block-to-show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="link-to-hover">Hover me to see the block</a>
<p>Anything else</p>
<p class="block-to-show">This block is shown only when the link is hocered</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.some_block{
   display:none;
}
a:hover .some_block{
   display:block;
}
</style> 
<a href="#">some url<div class="some_block">some block</div></a>
```

Comment: @FLK

1. отсутствует подход к дыбилобраузерам
2. блок будет выскакивать при наведении на любой тег `<a>`
3. наверное лучше использовать `javascript`?
4. зачем так приводить пример? лично я не сомневаюсь в твоих способностях, но это решение самое ужасное!

Comment: А по-моему нормальный тесткейс. Хотя я подозреваю, что у ОПа несколько вольная терминология касательно "блока" и имелось ввиду a:hover{outline:thick}

Comment: @Palmervan м.б. мне стоило сразу сайт написать? я показал принцип действия, а использование всегда остается на усмотрение задающего вопрос, по поводу js, что то я не заметил метки javascript  в вопросе. **p.s.** это что за дыбилобраузеры которые не поддерживают css2? и есть ли смысл в костылях для них?

Comment: @karmadro4 гадать можно сколько угодно.. будем ждать экстрасенса, либо когда @koko соизволит уточнить вопрос.

Comment: @FLK суть в том что ТС будет наследовать твой принцип действия и снова задавать пать десятков вопросов по этому же поводу! По поводу меток, хоть они и необозначены в вопросе, это не значит что ТС задавая вопрос имеет понятие о том что такое javascript, но используя знакомые функции onmouseover|out не костыль! На примере я когда только знакомился с html и css - javascript казался недостижимым. Это равно тот же случай!

Comment: > это не значит что ТС задавая вопрос имеет понятие о том что такое javascript! 
Вот именно. Если человек понятия не имеет о JS, то как раз в этом случае вопросов еще будет море. Хотя, с другой стороны, начинать когда-то надо, посему тут "палка о двух концах"

Comment: И собственно - я все понимаю в плане я привожу пример, но давайте вспомним наше начало и что мы знали, приведения кода как то рашели огромный знак вопроса в голове?

Comment: @Deonis холивар начали)))

Comment: Тут такое дело, ОП явно хочет CSS. Ответ, где ему впарят решение на JavaScript будет бесполезен.

> Симптомы выглядят так: любой вопрос, прежде чем на него будет дан ответ, приводится к правильному, каноническому виду, даже если в каментах большими буквами указана просьба этого не делать.

Comment: @Palmervan, в html5 внутрь тега `a` можно помещать блочные элементы.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="link" href="href">lnk</a>
<div id="bk">fea</div>
<script>
var lnk=document.getElementById("link");
var bk=document.getElementById("bk");
lnk.onmouseover=function(){bk.style.visibility="visible"}
lnk.onmouseout=function(){bk.style.visibility="hidden"}
</script>
<style>
#bk{
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 60px;
width: 60px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #000000;
visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: хм... а где у вас `event` используется внутри анонимной функции? или я недопонял?

Comment: просто для дебильных браузеров чтоб невыдавало ошибок!

Comment: пил сегодня? это не больше чем локальная переменная которая)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> отсутствует подход к дыбилобраузерам
> блок будет выскакивать при наведении на любой тег <a>
> наверное лучше использовать javascript?
> зачем так приводить пример? лично я не сомневаюсь в твоих способностях, но это решение самое ужасное!
> ```

Всё там нормально будет работать

> a:hover .some_block

такая конструкция указывает на то что это именно для блока внутри именно этого A.

Comment: Селектор-то дружелюбен к старым UA, а вот разметка невалидная (блок в внутри строчного элемента). Но я остаюсь при мнении, что тесткейс удовлетворительный, а процитированная критика к делу напрямую не относится.